# passing variable between view controllers

Tags: iphone

i'm having a variable in NSInteger which i want to pass from FirstViewController to SecondViewController. In viewDidload of FirstViewController i have this

```
SecondViewController*detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    detail.integer2= self.integer1;
    NSLog(@"VARIABLE PASSED----%d",detail.integer2 );
```

NSLog is showing exactly what i want to pass. my question is how can  i retrieve passed value in SecondViewController.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad ..come on chat..will be better there.

Answer (score 3):

In your SecondViewController you can just call `self.integer2`

Comment: How are you presenting your SecondViewController?  You'll need to hang on to your `*detail` pointer and present that particular instance of the ViewController.  If your `VARIABLE PASSED` log is working correctly then somehow you're presenting a different instance of SecondViewController.

Comment: The OP seems to be long gone, but I'm guessing that either: a) they were using Segues in Interface Builder, in which case the variable passing should've been in  `prepareForSegue` method, or b) their SecondViewController which was created in viewDidLoad was dealloced by ARC because the was no reference remaining at the end of the viewDidLoad method.  So the OP must have recreated a new instance to push or present the SecondViewController and therefore the variable was never passed to the actual instance presented.

Answer (score 2):

Make Property of `integer2` in `SecondViewController` and use as `self.integer2` in `SecondViewController`

Comment: Made property like this @Property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger integer2; in SecondViewController

Comment: Not working. Is there any problem with SecondViewController*detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"]; ?

Comment: See detail is allocated or not?

Comment: debug code and after this SecondViewController*detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
 Just hover mouse on detail..had u seen anything like 0X25462256 or any other in Yello color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7019/discussion-between-jason-and-marvin)